# Why are the following manual instructions not working (render/freestyle/export_svg)?

Tags: rendering

Just installed blender and need to generate an SVG file, but am not seeing the add-on that [the instructions](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/freestyle/export_svg.html?highlight=svg) mention.

[image]

Thanx, Alan

Comment: What version of Blender are you using ? The [Freestyle exporter](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.73/Freestyle) is bundled starting from version 2.72.1. Also you can `Shift` + click on both `Official` and `Communuity` checkmarks so to search in both categories simultaneously.

Comment: Splashcreen says 2.72b

Answer (score 1):

This add-on is under the *community* tab in your *user preferences>add-ons.*
 Search for *freestyle* and it will come up
[image]

Comment: I just did exactly what you showed and got nothing. I am using linux, if that makes a difference.

Comment: How do I show a screenshot here?

Comment: In comments pictures are disabled, but you can edit your question(this is encouraged when adding new information), there is an icon to add a picture, just drag and drop the file.

Comment: Added a screenshot to the original message and was going to add another with a search for "fr" which did generate a result, but was not allowed to.